# Разворот односвязного списка

Tags: list, коллекции

Написал метод разворота односвязного списка. Метод работает неверно, выдавая только одно значение не в правильном порядке. Подскажите где ошибка?

```
public void reverse(){

    Node currNode = head;
    Node prevNode = null;

    while (currNode != null){
        Node next = currNode.next;
        currNode.next = prevNode;

        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = next;
      }

    }
```

Comment: В этом коде нет вывода ничего никуда, проблему вашу не воспроизвести.  [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: 1) добавляйте код в вопрос, в комментах он нечитаем. 2) Вы выводите head переменную, но я не вижу, где вы в неё пишете новое значение. Если это старый head, то он указывает на конец списка, вы же список перевернули.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ОБновите ваш head как то так

```
public void reverse(){
    Node currNode = head;
    Node prevNode = null;

    while (currNode != null){
        Node next = currNode.next;
        currNode.next = prevNode;

        prevNode = currNode;
        currNode = next;
    }

    head = prevNode;
}
```